# CANBUS troubleshooting

Tags: power-supply, motor, emc, can, emi-filtering

I'm currently having some trouble communicating my motors to a Speedgoat real-time target machine.

**Setup**:
My current setup includes the Speedgoat IO691 (CANBUS) module (https://www.speedgoat.com/products/communication-protocols-can-fd-io691) connected to two AK10-9 motors (https://store.tmotor.com/goods.php?id=1148). Both motors are connected on the same CANBUS network and are powered by a 48V DC power supply bench (PSU) - https://docs.rs-online.com/5e3e/0900766b813ecd3c.pdf. The motors are encased within an aluminium chassis/robot which is connected to a steel boom (2.5m long). Simulink Real Time is the current platform to compile my simulations - commands are then sent to the motors via the IO691 module. Baud rate = 1.0 MBaud.

My wiring setup is simple, it has the CAN high and CAN low of the IO691 module connected to the CAN high and CAN low of the motors (using a shielded cable). Furthermore, the ground of the IO691 module is connected to the ground of the PSU. I've connected earth of the PSU to the robot's chassis and the foil of the shielded cable.

**Problem:**
My simulation is currently terminating as soon as the motors receives a CAN message. However, this problem only occurs when a high power rated PSU is used (I've used a smaller power rated PSU - also at 48V with the same setup and there weren't any problems). My assumption is that power supply is quiet noisy which is causing lots of interference in the CANBUS network.

On the other hand, my simulation works perfectly fine using both PSUs once the robot is disconnected from the boom.

**Proposed Solution:**
Unfortunately, I cannot include any spacers between the boom and robot as any rapid movement would cause it to snap. I've read up on common mode chokes as it helps reduce the common mode noise in the CAN network. However, there are risks such as the transient voltage being too high and might damage the transceiver. On the other hand, I could look into a method of filtering the PSU output (but the components used would be rather expensive) - zener diodes and a large capacitor in parallel.

Could anyone suggest the safe solution? Please let me know if you require any additional information

Comment: So it is difficult to understand what have you connected and how. Is the CAN bus correctly terminated at both ends? Is there a common ground reference connected between all CAN devices (it will not work without, so all boards must connect to CANH, CANL and GND).

Comment: Yep, there's a 120 ohm resistor on each end of the CAN bus network. And yes, all the grounds are connected at a single point

Comment: A simple schematic would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the motors before anything else. Most EMI from motors might be conducted noise, so you will likely be able to measure it with a scope. You need to narrow down the problem, is the noise on the CAN bus or on the supply (or elsewhere).

- In case there's noise on the bus (you may notice this with a scope or from the presence of CAN error frames) you could first of all use an CAN bus common mode filter (I always use this) and TVS. If that's not enough, then galvanically isolate the bus using digital isolators between transceivers and MCU. Ensure that the shield of your cables is only connected at one side.
- If you have reason to believe the supply itself is noisy - well, does the problem go away if you disconnect the motors and replace them with some static load? If not I'd suspect the supply, otherwise the motors. In case there's noise on the supply, add TVS and big bulk caps to deal with spikes and surges (anything taking supply from a mobile machine should always have this).

Comment: Hi Lundin, thank you for the solution :).  After scoping the PSU output and the CAN high signal, I noticed there were noisy components  (link to image, please note the FFT is derived from the PSU signal: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_gMP6nSl-rirTJds1G2LNx2Utm6P9wEq/view?usp=sharing). To suppress the noise, I wrapped the shielded CAN cable around an inductor which seemed to solve the problem. However, I am concerned this might interfere with the CANBUS timing. I think filtering the actual PSU would be best and currently looking to use a LC filter (along with a TVS diode in parallel)

Comment: @Zubair Not sure how you measured that, but if that's truly what your powered CAN line looks like, I don't think the situation is salvageable and you should look to redesign all of this. I can't believe that massive noise like that comes from the PSU though unless it's utterly broken. More likely you are measuring wrong, got the wrong ground reference or you got massive noise coming from the motors.

Comment: thank you for the response. I've scoped the CANH signal again. I focused scoping the signal when the robot is off (simulation works) and on the boom (simulation error). I've included images of my layout and the scopes [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DO3s2jbsaQ4SGduMnZOzQRscEIodMwQ4?usp=sharing]. Timing is as follows: send motor 1 message at 0s, read reply at 0.001s, send motor 2 message at 0.002s, read reply at 0.003s.

I've noticed that the CANH signal amplitude spikes when on the boom. Could you maybe direct me to what the issue might be? Is it still related to noise?

Comment: @Zubair What are those pictures, that's just random noise. Now I definitely start to think that there is something wrong with the way you measure... because all of this looks like missing scope probe ground, nothing else.

Comment: thank you for the speedy reply. I've included a README file indicating what each image represents in the image folder (the comment box has limited characters). I've also included images before the PSU is turned on and after it's turned on.

The way I've been scoping the CAN high signal was by connecting the probe to the CAN high connector terminal between the Speedgoat and motors. And I've connected the ground clip of the probe to the negative terminal of the PSU.

Comment: "negative terminal of the PSU" means what? Is it using a transformer? Because if you ground on the primary and measure on the secondary, that will obviously not work. Same thing if you use an isolated CAN bus. The picture doesn't resemble anything meaningful, at best they represent 50Hz line noise where you forgot to configure your scope for 10x probes. What signal do you get if you connect the probe to its own ground clip while also holding the probe against the board? Same one? Then that's your problem.

Comment: The PSU has three outputs: Earth, +48V DC and ground. I meant to say that the ground connector of the probe is connected to the ground of the PSU. The Speedgoat's CAN module is galvanically isolated but I connected the ground of the CAN module to the PSU ground. I've also set the probe to x1 (and set the ratio 1:1 on the oscilloscope) - should I use 10:1 on x10 instead? I'm confused when you speak about against the board, could you please clarify ?

Comment: I still strongly suspect that you have some fundamental measurement problem, since all these screenshots seem to contain is line noise, no actual signals. Broken ground clip on the probes is a common problem. Thus, if you connect the probe ground clip to the input of the probe and hold it against any random surface and get the same kind of noise even though the ground reference is now obviously non-existent, then that is the problem.

Comment: thank you for all your help. I've redone the measurements with different probes and they all display the same output. I ensured that the each probe check was passed. I've tried connecting the probe input to ground and held it up against the boom, robot and the floor but there weren't any signs of the noise (PSU was turned off when doing these tests). I've noticed the main difference to when the robot is on the boom compared to when it's off the boom is that the peak CAN voltages are amplified (when on the boom). Would using a common mode filter help reduce the peak voltage?

Comment: You don't have anything even remotely resembling a digital CAN signal. Until you figure out why that is, you can't fix the problem.

Comment: I've included new images in the folder ('updated measurements'). Three measurements with the robot off and three with the robot on the boom.
I've measured both the CAN high and CAN low (green and yellow signals) then subtracted the two to get the actual CAN message (purple). When the robot is off the boom, I can see the message structure looks reasonable but when on the boom, it displays damped oscillations. Are these CAN signals okay for the measurements?

Comment: You need to ground the probes better, at the CAN signal ground. It's impossible to tell what's actual noise and what's measurement errors. Use as short ground clips as possible. Also check if the scope uses one common ground for both probes or individual ones, I've seem both.

Comment: I've taken two of the same probes models and the measurements seemed to improve. In the update measurements folder there are three images (NEW_..) which are the updated measurements. Off the boom, the CAN high and CAN low signals can be seen (green and yellow) while the purple is the difference between the two. The 'on_boom' measurement doesn't resemble any CAN message at all. Could these measurements be used to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Hi @Lundin, I managed to fix the issue. I connected the Speedgoat CAN transceiver GND pin to the GND pins of the motors rather than the GND pin of the PSU. The signals improved and the simulation is working. I think what is happening is that the CAN network does not have a proper GND reference by the time it reaches the motors. Which explains why the probed signals looked like GND was not connected.  So by connecting the Speedgoat CAN transceiver GND directly on the GND terminals of the motors, it ensures that there is a common GND reference between the transceivers. Thank you for all the help